# Unable to compile this class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Consider:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Mybean cannot be resolved to a type
7: <title></title>
8: </head>
9: <body>
10: <jsp:useBean id="bean1" class="Mybean"/>
11: <jsp:setProperty name="bean1"
12:                     property="name"
13:                     value="bean1" />



An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Mybean cannot be resolved to a type
14:     <jsp:setProperty name="bean1"
15:                     property="id"
16:                     value="1" />
17:                     <jsp:getProperty name="bean1" property="name" />
18:                         <jsp:getProperty name="bean1" property="id" />
19:
20: </body>

org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I have made a Java class with Mybean name. I am making use of JSP to set attributes and get attributes. I am getting an error which I am not able to resolve.

Comment: did you import `Mybean`  in your jsp page ??

Comment: Mybean should be fully qualified, including package name. In your <jsp:usebean> tag

Comment: i havent made any package ,i am using default package

Comment: Is Mybean.class present in `WEB-INF/classes` folder of your webapplication deployed on your app server?

Comment: how should i eliminate the error??

Comment: @Oleg mikheev no there is no folder like that,it contains one folder lib and web.xml file only

Comment: Did you clean and build project and restarted tomcat?

Comment: @parlov yeah i did it?? i included class file under class folder in web-inf folder ,then also error is not rectified

Comment: Define the package.. Move the file under package.. Recompile and test..

Comment: yeah i did it and the error got rectified

Answer (score 2):

From the [JSP specification](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAB&url=http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245&ei=nSL9UOXxFIzP0AWDnoD4DA&usg=AFQjCNH2K39o6YIKJiYJHGTAVE6xfdZYDA&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k):

> As of JSP 2.0, it is illegal to refer to any classes from the unnamed (a.k.a. default) package.

So your bean must have a package declaration:

```
package foo;
public class MyBean {}
```

The package must be reflected in the application structure; e.g:

```
WEB-INF/classes/foo/MyBean.class
```

The qualified name must be used in the tag:

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean1" class="foo.MyBean"/>
```

Comment: yeah that was the foremost problem and i rectified it .Thanks