# Why can't I compile the class in the JSP file? Error 500

Tags: jsp, servlets

I just started studying JSP, and it goes well if there's a single JSP file.

I create a class file for testing JavaBeans and always get the error "Unable to compile class for JSP" and the web status 500.

---

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [9] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
person cannot be resolved to a type


---------------------------- The 'person'.class code ------------

import java.lang.*;

public class person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String sex;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

------------------------- The JSP file -------------------------

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Java Bean Actions</title>
</head>

<body><br/>

    <jsp:useBean id="person" class="person" scope="page"></jsp:useBean>

    <jsp:setProperty name="person" property="*" />
```

[1. Unable to compile the class "person"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZkTR.jpg)

[2. person.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4yol.jpg)

[3. The JSP file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLuUe.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your `person` class is located at `src` folder. Your bean `person` must have a package declaration.

More details can be found at *[Unable to compile this class for JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436217)*.

BTW, it's a bad idea to name your class like `person`,it should start with an uppercase,like this `Person`

Comment: I wanna cry for costing my much time. why must classes be in a Pack?  I always liked simple directories.